# Could not load type 'System.Management.Automation.PSSnapIn

Tags: powershell, system.management

I am remotely connected to Nano server 2016 by PowerShell. When I am trying to import a module, I get an error `Could not load type 'System.Management.Automation.PSSnapIn' from assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0`.

Comment: Which module are you trying to import?

Comment: It is a customized module. We have included many assemblies in it, one of which is System.Management.Automation.

Comment: Are you running PS 2.0 and does the Module require .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: Powershell version is 5.1 and the module requires .NET 4.5